# Calling a function vs calling a function in a callback

Tags: javascript, function, asynchronous, callback

I want to understand how the `getJSON` function is invoked differently in the following two situations. What is `getJSON` if it is not a callback function, when I don't wrap it inside an arrow function?
First:

```
btn.addEventListener("click", ()=> {
  getJSON(astroURL);
})
```

Second:

```
btn.addEventListener("click", getJSON(astroURL))
```

Comment: The first code snippet will execute `getJSON(astroURL)` when you click the button. The second one will execute it as soon as the JS is parsed, and nothing will happen on click, because you already called the function by adding `()` to it. And you are passing the result of that function call to the event listener, instead of the function itself. Another way of doing it: `addEventListener('click', getJSON.bind(null, astroURL))`

Answer (score 1):

The second argument to [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) is supposed to be the callback that is invoked each time the event occurs. Your first example is passing an arrow function as the callback, while your second example is passing the return value of `getJSON(astroURL)` to `addEventListener`, which is erroneous, unless the method itself returns a function.